# Deploying ZF2 application to a shared hosting

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a domain name as addon on. It is called www.myapp.cöm and because it ais an addon domain it is located at çtp://myrealdomain.cöm/myapp/

How I'll put those ZF2 files? I don't want to put all of them under çtp://myrealdomain.cöm/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

you had to place all you application public files in the myapp folder and can place all other files (modules) on different location and link it with the exact path in configuration file declaration for modules).

for ZEND library if your server configuration allow variable in .htaccess you can set ZF2=path to zend library and you can place the lib files any ware accessible in your host

Hi I had posted an answer for setting up zf2 application in shared hosting, hope this may help follow the link below

[ZF2 in shared hosting environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992654/zf2-installation-on-shared-hosting-server)