# Setting Up Zend Framework 2 On Live Apache Server

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2

I am finding it very difficult to understand how to install Zend Framework 2 on an account on my Apache server.

I have been through the documentation at http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html but it seems to talk about development on localhost environments and it is not very clear where commands should be run from (server or document roots). I have looked at YouTube videos but they seem to be from people on localhost or Windows servers.

I have searched for other tutorials but with no luck and I have tried to play around with this guide but it doesn't seem to be very clear to me on how to set this up.

For example:

> In order to build our application, we will start with the
>   ZendSkeletonApplication available on github. Use Composer
>   (http://getcomposer.org) to create a new project from scratch with
>   Zend Framework:
>
> php composer.phar create-project --repository-url="http://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install

Am I supposed to run this command from my server root or from my document public_html folder or one up from here? This is the main area that is causing me confusion (knowing where to install/place files).

In addition, where do I place the ZendSkeletonApplication files or is this done automatically and where do I install the composer (document root or server root)?

If anyone can give me a clear tutorial on setting this up on a live server it would be much appreciated.

There must be thousands of developers that have done this and there must be a guide out there somewhere, maybe the "good" old Penguin 2.0 update is now hiding it from my search queries...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used Zend Framework 2 specifically, but it looks like this tutorial is pretty straightforward - http://www.slideshare.net/e.zimuel/quick-start-on-zend-framework-2

Comment: That does look pretty straightforward... I will check it out tomorrow and let you know how I get on with it... Thanks

Comment: Hi streetlogics, this certainly put me in the right direction and mixed with the official tutorial it was actually quite straightforward to set up in the end

Answer (score 0):

this is an answer I wrote earlier which may find useful to set your zf2 framework in your shared [zf2 installation on shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992654/zf2-installation-on-shared-hosting-server/17007612#17007612)