# How do I install Zend Framework 2 and check if the installation works?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I need clear instructions for installing Zend Framework2 on a web host.

The hosting company is Ipage. Ipage already has Zend Engine installed, so it should support Zend Framework2.

Ipage does not provide ssh, so an ssh installation method would not work. I can only install by FTP'ing the files to the host.

I have Zend Framework Full Package as a zip file.  In the zip file are `bin`, `library`, and `resource` folders.  I have uploaded all those files to the server.

Issues:

- I think there are path settings I need to set, and I need help with those.
- after installation, I need to check if Zend Framework is working; is there a way to check that?

Here is what I have so far:

1. Downloaded ZendFramework - 2.2.1.zip
2. Extracted all the files from `bin`, `library`, and `resource` folders and uploaded them to the host.
3. I am stuck here, any help would be good.

Comment: do you have php setup on your local machine?

Comment: Here's a good Getting Started tutorial for ZF2: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

Comment: php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar install

Comment: I have to run that using ssh or something, but ipage does not allow ssh.

Comment: I do have php setup on local machine, but I want to setup on the host.

Comment: Try to use google before asking questions here > try [my tutorial on installing ZF2 on a local XAMPP environment](http://samminds.com/2012/07/zend-framework-2-installation-on-xampp-for-windows/)

Comment: Sam, as I said, I do not have ssh to the server and I am not using a window. It is also not a local environment.

Comment: @HongWeiWang What I would do is install it and set everything up on your local host, then FTP all the files to your server.

Comment: absolutely, doing this all manually would just be such a needless waste of time resource.

Comment: check this answer that I wrote for similar question

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992654/zf2-installation-on-shared-hosting-server/17007612#17007612

Comment: check this answer which I wrote for a similar question

[zf2 installation on shared hosting server][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992654/zf2-installation-on-shared-hosting-server/17007612#17007612

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these simple steps:

1) Use Composer to install Zend Framework on your local machine. This will generate the required autoloading etc for you.

2) Upload the files via FTP to your host.

Detail:

You must setup a local development envorinment on your machine, if you're using windows install something like Wamp/Xamp. This will install PHP/Apache etc for you.

To begin we will install the Skelleton Application to get started. Grab a copy from here:

```
https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication
```

you can either download the package, or use one of the methods in the config, Git etc. Git would be recommended, but I am assuming you don't have this installed, so downloading the package is fine.

bring up a terminal window (in windows hit windows key + r and type cmd). change to the directory you placed the package.

now use composer to do your installation for you, type this:

```
cd my/project/dir
cd ZendSkeletonApplication
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar install
```

Now you should be ready to upload to your server (I have skipped howto seutp your local environment etc).

Upload the whole directory structure to your web server, making sure the public folder in in your document root on the server. It should now work :)