# ZF2 redirect on public dir

Tags: zend-framework2

Hello I dont know what is the best way to redirect all on public. I'm doing on server, not on local.

On local I can make VHost and editd host file but when i put with FTP on server www.example.com I cant make vhost.

How now can do redirection on public ?

On www.example.com he list me directory structure :

```
config/
data/
init_autoloader.php
module/
public/
vendor/
```

I really don't know apache .htaccess any example how to do that redirection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to do it yourself. It’s done by your web hosting provider. It can point to the public_html folder instead of public but that doesn’t matter. So you can just add your other folders as siblings to the public_html and it’s done.

Answer (score 0):

The redirection part is taken care by the .htaccess files put under the root folder of host, below is my answer to one of this similar question, the link that shows how to host a ZF2 app in a shared hosting environment

[zf2 installation on shared hosting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992654/zf2-installation-on-shared-hosting-server/17007612#17007612)