# How to configure htaccess zf2 in subdomain of shared hosting

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework2, subdomain, shared-hosting

I have tried to host the zf2 framework in a sub domain of my shared hosting server but it gave 404- not found error. This is my current file structure.

[image]

In-order to point it to the public folder, i used the following code in htaccess (which is placed in the root of the subdomain (abc)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abc/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

if the main website is `www.example.com`, I will be able to get my subdomain website as `abc.example.com` Please advice..

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the instruction in my reply in the below question

[ZF2 in shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992654/zf2-installation-on-shared-hosting-server)

This will work only by accessing the site with abc.example.com and not www.example.com/abc